# Checking if there is a missing element ID

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic form with a button that adds and removes rows while assigning ids such as `Ingredient[1]`,`Ingredient[2]`,`Ingredient[3]`. However i want to figure out a way to check if somewhere along the way one is deleted, for example if `Ingredient[2]` is deleted i would then like the next row added to be `Ingredient[2]` and then after that since `Ingredient[3]` already exists the next one should be `Ingredient[4]`.

Here is my addRow function.

```
var x = 1;

function addRow() {
  var tr = '<tr>' +
    '<td>' +
    '<select name="ingredient[' + x + ']" id="ingredient[' + x + ']" class="form-control>' +
    '@foreach($ingrListRecipe as $ingrListRecipe)' +
    '<option value="{{ $ingrListRecipe->id }}">{{ $ingrListRecipe->name}}</option>' +
    '@endforeach' +
    '</select>' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[' + x + ']" class="form-control"></td>' +
    '<td><select name="measurement[' + x + ']" class="form-control">' +
    '<option value="Grams">Grams</option>' +
    '<option value="Tbsp">Tbsp</option>' +
    '<option value="Mililitres">ML</option>' +
    '</select>' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td style="text-align: center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">Remove Row</a></td>' +
    '</tr>';
  $('tbody').append(tr);
  x++;
};
```

And this is my removeRow function the if statement was something i was toying with to see what existed

```
$(document).on('click', ".remove", function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();

  i = 1
  if (document.getElementById('ingredient[' + i + ']')) {
    alert('Element Present ' + ' I= ' + i + ' X= ' + x);
    i++;
  } else {
    x = i;
    alert('Element Not Present ' + ' I= ' + i + ' X= ' + x);
  }
});
```

Update: Solved by changing to ingredient[] collections and using a foreach in the add.

```
function addRow(){
        var tr = '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' + 
                                '<select name="ingredient[]" id="ingredient[]" class="form-control>' +
                                '@foreach($ingrListRecipe as $ingrListRecipe)'+
                                    '<option value="{{ $ingrListRecipe->id }}">{{ $ingrListRecipe->name}}</option>'+
                                    '@endforeach'+
                                    '</select>'+
                                    '</td>' +
                                    '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control"></td>'+
                                    '<td><select name="measurement[]" class="form-control">'+
                                            '<option value="Grams">Grams</option>'+
                                            '<option value="Tbsp">Tbsp</option>'+
                                            '<option value="Mililitres">ML</option>'+
                                        '</select>'+
                                    '</td>'+
                                    '<td style="text-align: center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">Remove Row</a></td>'+
                                '</tr>';
                                $('tbody').append(tr);
                                     
    };
```

```
    foreach($ingredient as $key => $no)
        {
        $reIng = new RecipeIngredient();
        $reIng->recipeid = $recipe->id;
        $reIng->ingredientid = $no;
        $reIng->quantity = $quantity[$key];
        $reIng->measurement = $measurement[$key];
        $reIng->save();
        }
        return redirect()->back();
        return redirect('/home');
    }
```

Comment: You start at `x = 1`?

Comment: Yes i have set X right above the function ill edit it to show.

Comment: I recommend *not* using `[]` in IDs. These characters are used as part of selector syntax, referring to these IDs will be difficult.

Comment: I only need it for adding them to the database which is working fine as long as there are no gaps from 1-10 for example. if i just add 10 rows and enter the data its fine but if one is missing along the way i get an error.

Comment: If you delete rows, then submit the form without adding new rows, you'll still have gaps.

Comment: I suggest you fix the problem that requires IDs to be sequential, it will be easier than renumbering everything when you delete rows.

Comment: If you just use `name=ingredient[]` then the controller will collect all the inputs into an array by sequential order.

Comment: So if i just use name=ingredient[] it will pass them into the controller and how would i get access to each individual one? a foreach?

Comment: Im extremely new to this so im not 100% sure how i would go about adding ingredient , quantity and measurement to a database from their arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the global variable `x`, use a loop that looks for the first missing ID in the numeric sequence.

```js
function addRow() {
  let x = 1;
  while (document.getElementById(`ingredient[${x}]`)) {
    x++;
  }
  var tr = '<tr>' +
    '<td>' +
    '<select name="ingredient[' + x + ']" id="ingredient[' + x + ']" class="form-control>' +
    '@foreach($ingrListRecipe as $ingrListRecipe)' +
    '<option value="{{ $ingrListRecipe->id }}">{{ $ingrListRecipe->name}}</option>' +
    '@endforeach' +
    '</select>' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[' + x + ']" class="form-control"></td>' +
    '<td><select name="measurement[' + x + ']" class="form-control">' +
    '<option value="Grams">Grams</option>' +
    '<option value="Tbsp">Tbsp</option>' +
    '<option value="Mililitres">ML</option>' +
    '</select>' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td style="text-align: center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">Remove Row</a></td>' +
    '</tr>';
  $('tbody').append(tr);
};
```

Comment: Honestly this is a very bad solution because it requires redrawing all those elements, which is totally unnecessary when you can instead work with and adjust the elements you already have. Not only is this massive overhead from what the code does, it is also inperformant to say the least.

Comment: @connexo It doesn't redraw anything, it just appends the new row.

Comment: I think you misread it. The `tr` is not inside the loop, the loop is just being used to find the next available value of `x`.

Comment: I understand the task totally differently from you. Also your code will insert a new row in the gap with regard to id/name, instead of appending it at the end. My understanding is that OP has a table, and before someone does something that makes `addRow` run, user might have deleted already existing rows.

Comment: @connexo The new row is added at the end, but the IDs will fill in the gap.

Comment: So if you start with rows `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, then delete 3, then add another row, you'll get `1, 2, 4, 5, 3`

Comment: @OP so you never want to assign a new number to an existing element in a row?

Comment: That wasn't how I understood it, I thought he just wanted to fill in the gap when creating new rows. But I suspect this won't really solve his actual problem.

Comment: My understanding was if you start with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, then delete 3 resulting in 1, 2, 4, 5 this should be changed to 1, 2 , 3, 4 so it's always safe to count up and append.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show a function that updates the `id`s for the `select` elements.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="ingredient["]').forEach((select, index) => {
  select.id = `ingredient[${index+1}]`;
})
```

Comment: So this will go through my elements and make sure there are no gaps?

Comment: Exactly. The only downside is that it does this regardless of if it changes anything or not, a.k.a. regardless of necessity.

Comment: So how would i change this to include the other inputs i.e. quantity and measurement?

Comment: You should easily be able to adapt this to the other elements. E.g. for the inputs, the argument for querySelectorAll is `'[name^="quantity["]'`.